# ask cli SMAPI node.js interace is failing

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

I am trying to get some metrics via the nodejs module for the ask-cli.  here is my command and error:

```
ask smapi get-skill-metrics --skill-id amzn1.ask.skill.xxxxx --start-time 2020-10-14T12:45:00Z --end-time 2020-10-19T12:45:00Z --period PT1H --metric uniqueCustomers --stage live --skill-type custom --locale en-US > metrics.json 

[Error]: { "name": "AskSdkModelRuntime.DefaultApiClient Error" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes, my VPN was blocking the request.  It works now and here is an example data set.  now to figure out what it means:

```
Operation: getSkillMetricsV1
Payload:
{
  "skillId": "amzn1.ask.skill.xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxx",
  "startTime": "2020-10-14T12:45:00Z",
  "endTime": "2020-10-19T12:45:00Z",
  "period": "PT1H",
  "metric": "uniqueCustomers",
  "stage": "live",
  "skillType": "custom",
  "intent": null,
  "locale": "en-US",
  "maxResults": null,
  "nextToken": null
}

Response:
{
  "body": {
    "metric": "uniqueCustomers",
    "timestamps": [
      "2020-10-14T12:00:00Z",
      "2020-10-14T13:00:00Z",
      "2020-10-19T12:00:00Z"
    ],
    "values": [
      36,
      120,
      79,
      46 ]
  },
  "headers": [  ],

  "statusCode": 200
}
```